# Bootstrap Table unable to Show the json Data in Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i'm facing a strange issue. i have Successful json response from server.which i need to Show in my Bootstrap Table.But unfortunately i'm unable to display the Json Data in Bootstrap Table. i'm using AJAX to request the Data.

Below is my Code

```
<script>
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST', 
                  url:  'data/searchtransaction.php', 
                  data: 'startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate, 
              })
              // using the done promise callback
              .done(function(result) {
                  $('#searchResult').bootstrapTable({
                      data: result
                  });
              });
 </script>
```

And here is my HTML Code which is simple Table

```
<table 
   id="searchResult"
   data-pagination="true">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th data-field="receiver_name" data-sortable="true">Receiver Name</th>
       <th data-field="receiver_phone" data-sortable="false">Receiver Phone</th>
       <th data-field="createdAt" data-sortable="false">Created At</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Below is my Response

```
[{"receiver_name":"UNK","receiver_phone":"022847120069","createdAt":"2017-05-03 12:34:45"},{"receiver_name":"UNK","receiver_phone":"022820709041","createdAt":"2017-05-03 13:32:24"},{"receiver_name":"UNK","receiver_phone":"022820708047","createdAt":"2017-05-03 13:33:14"}]
```

The Problematic thing is, my final output is in **result** variable, if i put the the result variable then it shows nothing and not even any error. For example

```
.done(function(result) {
   $('#searchResult').bootstrapTable({
       data: result
   });
});
```

But if i put direct Json inside Data then it shows. For Example

```
.done(function(result) {
       $('#searchResult').bootstrapTable({
           data: [{"receiver_name":"UNK","receiver_phone":"022847120069","createdAt":"2017-05-03 12:34:45"},{"receiver_name":"UNK","receiver_phone":"022820709041","createdAt":"2017-05-03 13:32:24"},{"receiver_name":"UNK","receiver_phone":"022820708047","createdAt":"2017-05-03 13:33:14"}]
       });
    });
```

i event try to parse the data but also not get any success. Parse like below

```
.done(function(result) {
   var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(result);
   $('#searchResult').bootstrapTable({
       data: parsedJson
   });
});
```

here is my Complete Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {

              var start = moment(); //moment().subtract(29, 'days');
              var end = moment();

              $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
                  startDate: start,
                  endDate: end,
                  ranges: {
                     'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                     'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                     'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                     'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                     'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                     'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                  }

              },cb);

              cb(start, end);

              function cb(start, end) {
                  $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

                  var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
                  var endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                      url:  'data/searchtransaction.php', // the url where we want to POST
                      data: {   
                              'startDate':startDate,
                              'endDate':endDate
                            }, 
                  })
                  // using the done promise callback
                  .done(function(result) {
                      var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(result);

                      $('#searchResult').bootstrapTable({
                          data: parsedJson
                      });
                  });
              }

          });
          </script>
```

here is my HTML CODE

```
<table id="searchResult" data-pagination="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th data-field="receiver_name" data-sortable="true">Receiver Name</th>
     <th data-field="receiver_phone" data-sortable="false">Receiver Phone</th>
     <th data-field="createdAt" data-sortable="false">Created At</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

So need Community help to solve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to parse with JSON.parse()?

Comment: @user7908029 already Try, but that one also not working.

Comment: are you able to get the response in console?

Comment: @Nagaraju yes if i print on console then i get the same Json response as i mentioned in Question.

Comment: @Nagaraju i can the response by using Inspect Element under Network Tab

Comment: speicify `dataType: 'json',` in ajax and check

Comment: @Nagaraju Thanks for reply. but when i include **dataType: 'json'**, then it shows me below result 

**[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**

Comment: where does it show? you mean in the table or console

Comment: @Nagaraju, Console it is showing perfect but when i'm printing it on screen using this command:  $('#showData').text(result);  then it Show as **[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**

Comment: @Nagaraju actually no need to add **dataType: 'json'**, Since my data already coming in form of JSON. Result is coming correct, there is no issue in JSON Result. As i mentioned in my Question that if i put Direct JSON result in the place of response then it shows but the problem is response also returning the same.

Comment: @Nagaraju are you still Online ????

Comment: if you are viewing response as Object.... use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: actually you need not parse if you specify `dataType:'json'`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `Append()` data in success function, this is my sample code it's perfectly worked for me.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "resources/php/LetterManage.php",
    data: {loadRecentTable: true},
    success: function (data) {

        var recentTable = JSON.parse(data).recentTable;
        $('#recent_insert_table tbody').empty();
        $.each(recentTable, function (index, element) {

            $('#recent_insert_table tbody').append("<tr><td>" + element[0] + "</td><td>" + element[1] +
                    "</td><td>" + element[2] + "</td><td>" + element[3] + "</td></tr>");

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Append is working but the Table looks like very ugly.

Comment: This is how it is working for me 

`var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
                      $.each(obj, function() {
                           $('#searchResult tbody').append('<tr><td>' + this['receiver_name'] + '</td><td>' + this['receiver_phone'] + '</td><td>' + this['createdAt'] + '</td></tr>');
                      }); `